# Borel-Cantelli-Lemmas

Tags: probability

Using the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, slolve the following:

Prove that for any sequence of real random variables $(X_n,n\geq1)$, there exists a sequence of constants $(c_n,n\geq1)$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=\infty$ and such that $\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{c_n}=0\right)=1.$

My solution so far:
$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_n}{c_n}=0\right)=1$ means that $\frac{X_n}{c_n}$ converges almost surely to $0$. Thus I know it converges in probability i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(|X_n|>\epsilon\cdot|c_n|\right)=0$.
I know, Im looking for a sequence $\epsilon\cdot|c_n|$ such that $\sum\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon\cdot|c_n|)$ is finite. But I don't know how to find it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Demonstration Using Borel Cantelli Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205742/demonstration-using-borel-cantelli-lemma)

Answer (score 1):

See that $\lim_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>N)=0$. Then you can select proper $c_n$, such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon c_n)<1/2^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it enough to realize, that I can now chose a $c_n$ or do I have to explicitly choose it?

Comment: Yes, it is enough. You can deduce that such $c_n$ exists. You do not need to choose it explicitly. Actually, you can not choose $c_n$ explicitly unless you know the exact distribution that $X_n$ obeys.

Comment: $\lim_{N\to+\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>N)=0$ means there exists a $N_0$ large enough, such that the inequality $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>N)<1/2^n$ holds for any $N\geq N_0$. Then you can just choose $c_n=N_0/\epsilon$. But $N_0$ here is implicit, which is dependent on the distribution of $X_n$. So does $c_n$. You can prove its existence, but can not choose it explicitly.